# kivy app in android with buildozer, terminal loops on "# Waiting for application to start."

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer, kivymd

I made a sample "hello world" app with kivy and I am trying to put it on an android tablet.

I used a virtual machine (Virtual Box) and bulldozer to load it onto the tablet. However, when I run it the terminal, it just prints in a loop

`# waiting for the application to start`

Any idea on what could be the problem, or how can I start the application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled developer mode on the phone, the phone must be plugged in to the VM (In VirtualBox: Devices -> USB -> {phone}) and that the screen is unlocked.

On the phone you should see a "USB debugging connected" notification when it's plugged in.

If the phone is properly connected, you'll see it in Android Studio in a number of places, including the LogCat and right at the top of the screen in a little dropdown to the left of the run button.

Lastly, you can run the app manually and then connect the debugger if you want. Just run the app on the phone, then click the little icon in the top right with the green bug with an arrow over it.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this too. But if it runs that far then it should've successfully compiled the `.apk`. It should be in the same folder that you ran the `buildozer` command. You can even run an HTTP server with `buildozer serve` and access it via `localhost:THE_PORT_NUMBER_HERE`. Then you can just transfer or download the `.apk` to your device. And then install and run it after accepting the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing the command `buildozer android debug deploy run` remove "deploy run" just write `buildozer android debug` without plugging your phone. Then you can copy and install your app on your phone manually.